# Mocking for Catch - C++ testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, catch-unit-test

Could you, please, suggest me a mocking system to use with Catch for testing C++? I'd really like one that does NOT require me to define any new classes (like I saw Google Mock does) :), something like Mockito for Java. I've checked Mockitopp and Fakeit so far. The problem with Fakeit is that it does not support multiple inheritance, while Mockitopp seems to have less features than Fakeit (and I don't know whether it supports multiple inheritance or not). What's nice about Fakeit is that it actually seems to have integration with Catch and many other testing frameworks.

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any realistic (i.e. usable and mature) alternatives to Google Mock?